# What does this assembly statement means

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm new in assembly language, and I don't know what does this part of the assembly program mean in data segment!

```
buff   db 11
          db  ?
          db 11 dup(0)
```

Is it a variable? or not?
Can somebody explain it please?

Comment: Puts the byte `11` into memory followed by an uninitialized value then 11 zeroes. You can use the name `buff` to refer to the beginning. Consult your assembler's manual.

Comment: So it means that we have 13 bytes here?

Comment: @Fad, yes, 1 byte + 1 byte + 11 byte = 13 bytes. :). Twelve of them are initialized, and one is not. This is all in the assembler documentation.

Comment: Obviously a program that uses [`int21h/ah=0Ah`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm). `buf` is just a label identifying the begin of the input buffer.